# Python/Django: as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: django, arguments, django-views, django-urls

I have written an as_view() in my Django project in which two positional arguments are given to submit a form. When rendering the template it raising a type error : as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. I would appreciate helping me in solve this.

Views.py:

```
class AuctionView(LoginRequiredMixin, MultipleFormsView):
    template_name = 'loggedin_load/active_deals.html'
    form_classes = {'accept_bid': AuctionForm,
                'accepted': AcceptedForm}
    success_url = '/live_bids/'


    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(not_in_company_group, login_url='/login/'))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AuctionView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


    def accept_bid_form_valid(self, request, post_id, bid_id, form):

        accept_bid = form.save(commit=False)
        accept_bid.bid = bid
        accept_bid.post = post
        accept_bid.post_owner = request.user
        accept_bid.save()
        form.save()
        return form.accept_bid(self.request, redirect_url=self.get_success_url())

    def accepted_form_valid(self, form):
        accepted = form1.save(commit=False)
        return form.accepted(self.request, user, self.get_success_url())
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<post_id>[\w-]+)/bid/(?P<bid_id>[\w-]+)/$', AuctionView.as_view, name='accept_bid'),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
url(r'^post/(?P<post_id>[\w-]+)/bid/(?P<bid_id>[\w-]+)/$', AuctionView.as_view(), name='accept_bid'),
```

Comment: I am getting an error :'NoneType' object is not callable. Can you help me what is this about!!

Comment: Certainly. please be so kind as to post a new question with the full error traceback